# Disallow bootstrap modal to close on clicking anywhere on screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text which when clicked should display a modal window -

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalid">Open</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #F0F0F0">
        Content
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have used `data-backdrop="static"` for preventing the window to close by clicking anywhere on the screen, but it is not working. Window is still getting closed. (Note: another attribute `data-keyboard="false"` is working fine)

One more thing, I saw that this class is always getting attached to the html, just above `div class="modal-dialog"` line-

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

Is this causing the issue? How to fix it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The code you posted works fine (if you fix the missing `>` at the end of the first line)

Comment: That was just a typo. This is the same code I checked on fiddle too, and it works fine, but somehow does not in my application. What can be the reason for addition of modal-backdrop class?

Comment: The additional class is not a problem, that's how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just to prove your code is already working as required, here it is in a runnable snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalid">Open</div>

  
<div class="modal fade" id="modalid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #F0F0F0">
        Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't working for me. And I just noticed another thing, that clicking on close button is not closing the window. The roles have reversed somehow.

Comment: The snippet I posted isn't working, or it isn't working in your project?

Comment: There's nothing else anyone can help with unless you post more from your project. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I found the issue. My modal class code was INSIDE the above div (with data-toggle="modal") and not below it. Pheww.

Comment: My mistake in pasting a wrong code, didn't think it would be the issue.